# Xtext, import another project in MyDsl project

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I'm using Xtext to make a Dsl. In my interpreter class, I need to use classes from another project.[Here is my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziUDG.png)

My actual project is `org.xtext.example.mydsl` and I need to use classes from the `jDLMS` project
I use it in this line:

```
import com.sagemcom.test.LoadProfile
class MyDslInterepeter {
val Jtest = new LoadProfile()
```

I first tried to add the project in the build path. when I ran the mydsl project, it works. But in the second instance of eclipse when running the file with the .mydsl extension, it fails with the "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sagemcom/test/LoadProfile`" exception.
  I also tried exporting the project into a jar file and add it in the build path -> libraries. It also fails with the same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution here 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731406/cannot-add-libraries-to-xtext-project-in-eclipse-returns-error?rq=1)

1. copy it to a new lib folder inside the plugin
2. adapt the manifest and add the jars as entries (runtime tab, classpath section)
3. add the jars to be included in build.properties

Answer (score 0):

jDLMS should be deployed as an eclipse plugin in the second instance and your plugin (`org.xtext.example.mydsl`) should have a dependency to it. Is it so?

Comment: my plugin `org.xtext.example.mydsl` should have access to jDLMS, yes right. jDLMS has not necessarily to be deployed as an eclipse plugin, it depends on the solution.

Comment: Is JDLMS a eclipse plugin project? If not you should make it and add as a dependency to it `org.xtext.example.mydsl` via manifest file.